# jquery.avgrund popup. How to call it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, popup, avgrund

Below is my php file called invalid_file_popup.php, I have all the code written for the popup and I've tested it with

```
    <div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" id="show" class="button left">Show it</a>
    </div>
```

and that ^^^ works fine. But i want to include it into a different page and call this 'show' function if its in this if-else statement.. Anyone know how to call it?

invalid_file_popup.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Headland+One|Open+Sans:400,300&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://labs.voronianski.com/media/style/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/invalid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/av_invalid.css">
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">   
</script>
<script src="./js/jquery.avgrund.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#show').avgrund({
        height: 150,
        holderClass: 'custom',
        showClose: true,
        showCloseText: 'close',
        onBlurContainer: '.container',
        template: "<p>Error. Either all the correct required (*) fields were't entered or image file was invalid.</br></br>" +
        "File must be jpeg, jpg, pjpeg, x-png or png.</p>"          
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

At the bottom of this code is where I want to call the javascript function so it makes the popup.. Where I have include invalid_file_popup.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if ((($image_type == "image/gif")
|| ($image_type == "image/jpeg")
|| ($image_type == "image/jpg")
|| ($image_type == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($image_type == "image/x-png")
|| ($image_type == "image/png"))
&& ($image_size < 205000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
   {
   echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
  else
   {
   echo "Upload: " . $image_name . "<br>";
   echo "Type: " . $image_type . "<br>";
   echo "Size: " . ($image_size / 1024) . " kB<br>";
   echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
   // redirect somewhere

   if (file_exists("upload/" . $image_name))
     {
     // redirect somewhere and let user know it already exists
    echo $image_name . " already exists. ";
    }
   else
    {

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Events (event_name, event_venue, event_info, event_price,     
    event_day, event_month, event_year, event_online, event_contact, image_name, image, 
    user_id) VALUES ('$event_name', '$event_venue', '$event_info', '$event_price', 
    '$event_day', '$event_month', '$event_year', '$event_online', '$event_contact', 
    '$image_name', '$image',".$_SESSION['id'].")");

  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $image_name);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $image_name;
  echo "SUCCESSFULLY ADDED EVENT";

  $path = "/upload/$image_name";
  echo "<img src='".$path."' />";


 }
 }
  }
 else
{
 include "invalid_file_popup.php";
 // HAVE INCLUDED THE FILE NOW I WANT TO MAKE THE CALL!
}
}
```

Comment: Once you have included the file, you can call it the same way as you would anywhere. I don't know what `avgrund` does but you shouldn't be having any problem calling it. But keep in mind, the place where you include, all the code of that file will be printed (like the html, stylesheets etc.) this may cause conflict with the page including it.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger and how do I call it? I dont want to have a button to call it.. I just want it to pop up if that if-statement is called. Get me?

Comment: You could try wrapping the `$('#show').avgrund({})` into some _function_ let's say `show_func()` and call it in your PHP as `echo '<script>show_func()</script>;`